# Spring boot JPA @Version and @Transactional not working together

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring JPA + Hibernate and on one of my entities I have added a version column to ensure multiuser update support. The entity have is a `Long` with the `@Version` annotation.

Now in my service where I inject a standard `JpaRepository` I need to annotate the service class with `@Transactional` to for another usecase, but just adding the transactional annotation on my service breaks the version handling. Now I can give any value to the version field, and JPA will automatically set the correct value before saving, and therefore not showing the conflict error when trying to update with the wrong version value from the client.

I can't find any doc on this - and why just adding @Transactional to the service class should change the @Version logic?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl")
public class SomeEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Version
    private Long rowVersion;
    private String value;
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface SomeEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeEntity, Long> {}
```

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class SomeService {
    private final SomeEntityRepository rep;

    public void update(Long id, Long rowVersion, String value) {
        var entity = rep.findById(id).get();
        entity.setValue(value);
        entity.setRowVersion(rowVersion);
        rep.save(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: " I need to annotate the service class with `@Transactional` " > you can put `@Transactional` on methods, too, not just classes. Doesn't answer your question but maybe it solves your problem.

Comment: @julaine it will not solve it, as the update method using `@Version` will also need the logic that is introduced together with the transactional need

Comment: `@Transactional` shouldn't break the versioning support, so this makes me believe you are using it in a wrong way (the versioning support that is).

Comment: @M.Deinum I might, but I don't know what is wrong - I have update the question with some code example (a little simplified) but I do not do anything else then fetch data, update it - and then save it. It all works as expected without `@Transactional` annotation, but when I add it to the service class, it stops working, and just correct the rowValue before saving

Comment: YOu must not manage the version yourself that is the job for hibernate, that is the whole point of `@Version`. If you want to use it to make sure you are updating the proper version from the database you first need to detach it from the session (which is why it (appears) to work without a transaction as this detaching is then happening.

Comment: If you get all of the state through the web, just bind and store instead of retrieve, copy and store.

Comment: @M.Deinum do you have an resource with that example - might be useful, however I don't always get the entire state from web but only a subset of fields - thanks

Comment: Not sure if there is a resource on that except for how version works (and how you should not set it on managed enitites). Adding a `entitymanager.detach(yourentity);` will solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have to manually update the version field for such simple scenarios. See here on proper usage of the version-column: https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-entity-version-property-hibernate/

Completely drop the line `entity.setRowVersion(rowVersion);`. If you want to check if a user has the most recent version of a row, you can check if the version number from the database matches expectations, but you should not set it since hibernate appends incrementing the version number to the update-statements it generates.

Comment: Okay - I was under the impression that I could use it in the same was as rowversion (SQL Server) or xmin (Postgres) in my update queries, relying on a concurrency exception from the storage layer, instead of manually checking it each place, as the version in the database could might aswell be changed after I check the version in the application, and then saves it - making the version check duplicated?

Comment: as far as I am aware, the purpose of of the @Version-column in hibernate is to implement optimistic locking (to make sure your version column is as expected when your operation completes). It is a hibernate-feature, not a database-feature. For that usecase, you don't need to check. But I was under the impression that your usecase was to check if the user (on the other side of an api) has the most recent version of a row before proceeding with his command. Is that right?

Comment: yes, it is to ensure that the service on the other side of an API is only can update the data, if it is the same version as stored in the database - but this still means that I then need to check the version in the service layer, when loaded from the database, and also catch concurrency exceptions in the database to solve the general problem, instead of "just change" the version value in the update, and rely on the concurrency exception from the storage layer

Comment: Yes, two checks are necessary because those are two different problems. For both of the checks you can find a scenario where only that check fails, so I don't see how to eliminate either of them.

But I do not really see how that would have worked before you had the `@Transactional`-service